# Elastic Stack (Filebeat collect logs into Elasticsearch) wastes lots of storage (disk) spaces?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am playing with Elastic stack - use a Filebeat to collect `.log` files into Elasticsearch (and visualize via Kibana). However, I see the data stored in Elasticsearch is *quite huge* for a simple single line of raw log.

For example, a `.log` file may contain a line (which takes less than 30 bytes):

```
INFO This is a line of log
```

But IMHO Filebeat will transform it into something like the following. Hey *this is quite huuuuuuuge!*

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-7.8.0-2020.08.04-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1nSruXMBx-9kAPowKFuj",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2020-08-04T13:31:06.863Z",
    "agent": {
      "version": "7.8.0",
      "hostname": "minikube",
      "ephemeral_id": "ad8494d4-f9de-434f-bc33-25a1d456062b",
      "id": "15191fd6-5274-430a-b66a-d6d772529892",
      "name": "minikube",
      "type": "filebeat"
    },
    "message": "INFO This is a line of log",
    "log": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/var/log/containers/storage-provisioner_kube-system_storage-provisioner-db4f5b692edf2b06d3a65438168f937e8160ff808ced837a2b1ce41d415fccb9.log"
      },
      "offset": 25811285
    },
    "stream": "stderr",
    "input": {
      "type": "container"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "labels": {
        "addonmanager_kubernetes_io/mode": "Reconcile",
        "integration-test": "storage-provisioner"
      },
      "container": {
        "name": "storage-provisioner",
        "image": "gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v1.8.1"
      },
      "node": {
        "name": "minikube"
      },
      "pod": {
        "uid": "eb68d1c7-70c4-4ba7-8878-79419b3d57a7",
        "name": "storage-provisioner"
      }
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.5.0"
    },
    "host": {
      "mac": [
        "02:42:ff:0e:4e:ae",
        "36:e6:7a:83:ca:d5",
        "76:bf:3e:91:6b:65",
        "6a:62:f0:dc:c2:d6",
        "3e:5a:f5:4e:61:85",
        "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "e6:dc:92:3d:09:95",
        "1e:27:ff:d1:d2:2f",
        "c6:63:33:21:38:19",
        "de:19:b8:02:f0:e7",
        "ca:cf:25:b4:12:e4"
      ],
      "name": "minikube",
      "hostname": "minikube",
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "os": {
        "codename": "Core",
        "platform": "centos",
        "version": "7 (Core)",
        "family": "redhat",
        "name": "CentOS Linux",
        "kernel": "4.19.76-linuxkit"
      },
      "id": "83a8f1f835d84a9a9bf5417cecaf0c8e",
      "containerized": true,
      "ip": [
        "172.18.0.1",
        "172.17.0.2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "cef.extensions.flexDate1": [],
    "netflow.flow_end_microseconds": [],
    "netflow.system_init_time_milliseconds": [],
    "netflow.flow_end_nanoseconds": [],
    "misp.observed_data.last_observed": [],
    "netflow.max_flow_end_microseconds": [],
    "file.mtime": [],
    "aws.cloudtrail.user_identity.session_context.creation_date": [],
    "netflow.min_flow_start_seconds": [],
    "misp.intrusion_set.first_seen": [],
    "file.created": [],
    "misp.threat_indicator.valid_from": [],
    "process.parent.start": [],
    "azure.auditlogs.properties.activity_datetime": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.ProcessStartTime": [],
    "zeek.ocsp.update.this": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.IncidentStartTime": [],
    "netflow.observation_time_microseconds": [],
    "event.start": [],
    "cef.extensions.agentReceiptTime": [],
    "cef.extensions.oldFileModificationTime": [],
    "checkpoint.subs_exp": [],
    "event.end": [],
    "netflow.max_flow_end_milliseconds": [],
    "netflow.min_flow_start_nanoseconds": [],
    "zeek.smb_files.times.changed": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.StartTimestamp": [],
    "netflow.flow_start_nanoseconds": [],
    "netflow.flow_start_seconds": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.ProcessEndTime": [],
    "zeek.x509.certificate.valid.until": [],
    "misp.observed_data.first_observed": [],
    "netflow.exporter.timestamp": [],
    "netflow.monitoring_interval_start_milli_seconds": [],
    "cef.extensions.oldFileCreateTime": [],
    "event.ingested": [],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-08-04T13:31:06.863Z"
    ],
    "zeek.ocsp.update.next": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.UTCTimestamp": [],
    "tls.server.not_before": [],
    "cef.extensions.startTime": [],
    "netflow.min_flow_start_milliseconds": [],
    "azure.signinlogs.properties.created_at": [],
    "cef.extensions.endTime": [],
    "suricata.eve.tls.notbefore": [],
    "zeek.kerberos.valid.from": [],
    "cef.extensions.fileCreateTime": [],
    "misp.threat_indicator.valid_until": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.EndTimestamp": [],
    "misp.campaign.last_seen": [],
    "cef.extensions.deviceReceiptTime": [],
    "netflow.observation_time_seconds": [],
    "crowdstrike.metadata.eventCreationTime": [],
    "cef.extensions.fileModificationTime": [],
    "tls.client.not_before": [],
    "zeek.smb_files.times.created": [],
    "zeek.smtp.date": [],
    "netflow.collection_time_milliseconds": [],
    "zeek.pe.compile_time": [],
    "netflow.max_flow_end_seconds": [],
    "tls.client.not_after": [],
    "netflow.flow_start_milliseconds": [],
    "event.created": [],
    "package.installed": [],
    "zeek.kerberos.valid.until": [],
    "suricata.eve.flow.end": [],
    "netflow.observation_time_milliseconds": [],
    "netflow.flow_start_microseconds": [],
    "tls.server.not_after": [],
    "netflow.flow_end_seconds": [],
    "process.start": [],
    "suricata.eve.tls.notafter": [],
    "zeek.snmp.up_since": [],
    "azure.enqueued_time": [],
    "netflow.max_flow_end_nanoseconds": [],
    "misp.intrusion_set.last_seen": [],
    "netflow.min_flow_start_microseconds": [],
    "netflow.observation_time_nanoseconds": [],
    "cef.extensions.managerReceiptTime": [],
    "file.accessed": [],
    "netflow.flow_end_milliseconds": [],
    "misp.campaign.first_seen": [],
    "netflow.min_export_seconds": [],
    "suricata.eve.flow.start": [],
    "suricata.eve.timestamp": [
      "2020-08-04T13:31:06.863Z"
    ],
    "cef.extensions.deviceCustomDate1": [],
    "cef.extensions.deviceCustomDate2": [],
    "netflow.monitoring_interval_end_milli_seconds": [],
    "file.ctime": [],
    "crowdstrike.event.IncidentEndTime": [],
    "zeek.smb_files.times.accessed": [],
    "zeek.ocsp.revoke.time": [],
    "zeek.x509.certificate.valid.from": [],
    "netflow.max_export_seconds": [],
    "zeek.smb_files.times.modified": [],
    "kafka.block_timestamp": [],
    "misp.report.published": []
  }
}
```

IMHO, this will cause log files indexed in Elasticsearch (with Filebeat) to ***be >10x bigger***  than the raw `.log` files. This is quite unacceptable since disk spaces cost money.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this? Or do I make a mistake? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Which version of the stack are you using? 7.8.0? The empty fields are not sent by filebeat, but a bug in kibana that appears to be solved in [7.8.1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/58418), but filebeat also add other fields depending on which processors you have enabled, what is your filebeat config? You can drop fields in filebeat before sending or use logstash for that.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks! Do you mean the `"fields": ...`? IMHO even if those fields are removed, there is still a *huge* overhead - for instance, `_source.agent.*`, `_source.kubernetes.*`, etc. In traditional MySQL database, those should be normalized into another table and will reduce the space usage.

Comment: Yes, the `fields` field that shows empty is a bug in 7.8.0. It can have a little overhead, it is how filebeat works, it will add fields to enrich your data and help you search it, some are information about itself, like `agent` others are information about configured modules like `kubernetes`. You can always remove fields before sending and you can also send your data to logstash for manipulation. Your final index can be larger or smaller than your original data, it will depend on how are you sending, number of shards, mappings etc.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks! I am a little bit confused. You mentioned "Your final index can be larger or smaller than your original data". But how can it be smaller (or at least, not a *lot* bigger), given all those things like  `_source.agent.*`, `_source.kubernetes.*`, etc?

Comment: As I said, it depends on some factors. In your example it can be larger, your original log is just a single line and filebeat is adding a lot of fields, but you can't assume that it will always be this way. Also, elasticsearch compress your data and you can change the compression type. For what are you planning to use elasticsearch? What kind of data? How you want to search? These questions will help you to plan your cluster. I would not care too much about index size when you are just playing with it.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks! I use ES with Kibana to store logs and search them. You know, just the classical ELK stack (and now "L" seems to be replaced by Beats). I will have a look at the compression.